# Filter <msg> from SVN Log to Pick up only Ticket Number

Tags: python, perl, parsing, svn, xml-parsing

I am using python to convert and XML log of SVN to CSV...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import subprocess
import sys
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

log_text = subprocess.Popen(['svn', 'log', '--xml'] + sys.argv[1:],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
log_xml = etree.XML(log_text)

csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

for child in log_xml.getchildren():
        csv_writer.writerow([
                child.attrib['revision'],
                child.findtext('date'), 
                child.findtext('author').encode('utf-8'),
                child.findtext('msg').encode('utf-8'),
        ])
```

It will give the output for example...

```
2022,2013-01-02T06:11:40.500850Z,dave.d@email.com,"Ticket 16057735 - Blah "
2023,2013-01-02T06:43:22.247709Z,john.c@email.com,Ticket:16060718 Blah Blah
2027,2013-01-02T07:43:00.326583Z,dave.d@email.com,Ticket 16060936 - Blah Blah
```

But I want to filter / parse the `<msg>` to pick up only the ticket number while creating the .csv output.

Any alternatives like using perl is not a problem.

**Update:** Any way to skip the logs of the revisions not having the Ticket #### in the comment (`<msg>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution: look for the first number after the word Ticket:

```
if ($line =~ /Ticket\D+(\d+)/)
{
    $ticket_number = $1;
}
```

Using Perl syntax, but it should be easy in Python as well.

Here is a stab at a Python version (Caveat, I'm not a Python programmer):

```
matchObj = re.match( r'Ticket\D+(\d+)', child.findtext('msg').encode('utf-8'))

if matchObj:
   print matchObj.group(1)
```

The regex `Ticket\D+(\d+)` matches the word ticket, then one or more characters that are not digits (`\D+`), then one or more digits (`\d+`).  The parentheses capture the enclosed portion of the pattern in the first matching group.

If you want the match to be more specific, you could use `(\d{8})` to make sure the ticket number has eight digits.

**Update:** both of these solutions use an `if` statement to indicate that the pattern matched.  You can skip the lines that don't have a ticket number simply by skipping the lines that don't match.

Comment: I am getting the correct result but how to add it to the csv_writer ?

Comment: @DebajyotiDas, I suggest you try incorporating it yourself.  Ask further questions if you have trouble.

Comment: Hope i am not bothering you. I am bad with Regex... In the msg I have `Ticket ### - Blah` as well as `JIRA-XXX - Blah`. Any way to tweak the regex to pick `###` and `JIRA-XXX` only ?